# Excel Average Function with Multiple criteria in the same column

Tags: excel

I am trying to calculate the average of the units for specific criteria in multiple columns in excel, but having an error saying "You've entered too many arguments for this function".

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? See the image above[image]

Code
Two columns
=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A:$A,{21,22},0))*($B:$B<>""),$B:$B))*1000

All columns
=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A:$A,{21,22},0))*($B:$B<>""),$C:$C,1,$D:$D,"<>"&"WTIR",$B:$B))*1000

Comment: `=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A:$A,{21,22},0))*($B:$B<>"")*(C:C=1)*(D:D<>"WTIR"),B:B))*1000`

Comment: Silly question, but are you on 365?

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks!